# get item by index in ItemFileWriteStore

Tags: dojo

I have an ItemFileWriteStore where there is no identifier specified,  so I don't believe I can use getItemByIdentity to retrieve an item.

Is there a way to get an item from store by the index of the item? The value in _0 ?

I need to retrieve an item from the store by index to update it.

What am I missing?

Currently I am using the grid's getSelected() to get the item see below.  But is there a method on the store that I can use to get an item by index when I am not working with a grid???

```
var formValues = myForm.get("value");

var curIndex = myCurrentItemIndex;
var gridItem;
var store = dijit.byId('myGrid').store;
if (curIndex == 'NEW') {
    store.newItem(formValues);
    store.save();
} else {
//How do I get item from store when I am not working with a grid
gridItem = dijit.byId('myGrid').selection.getSelected()[0];
var key;
for (key in formValues) {
    store.setValue(gridItem, key, formValues[key])
    }
    store.save();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without an identifier store items cant be defined. Dojo may throw errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I just thought that since the grid implemented a method to getSelected(), that it was possible to do the same when not using a grid. Thanks again for your response.